# Dotnet core code sample for using DescribeInstancesAsync for getting AWS EC2 instance data

Tags: c#, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, .net-core

I've used the AWS sample project with .NET Framework 4.6.1 and that had a `DescribeInstances` method which worked. When trying to move the sample code to ASP.NET Core I find that I have to use `DescribeInstancesAsync`. I cannot figure out how to get the `DescribeInstancesResponse`.

```
// Print the number of Amazon EC2 instances.
IAmazonEC2 ec2 = new AmazonEC2Client();
DescribeInstancesRequest ec2Request = new DescribeInstancesRequest();
DescribeInstancesResponse ec2Response;
IAsyncResult asyncResult;

asyncResult = ec2.DescribeInstancesAsync(ec2Request);

while(!asyncResult.IsCompleted) 
{
        // Do some work
}
try 
{
        // ec2Response = 
}
catch (Exception ex) 
{
        Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
}
```

I'm using AWSSDK.EC2 version 3.3.152.1 and ASP.NET Core 3.1

Comment: It looks like a standard async method - have you tried just `await`ing it? (i.e. `var result = await ec2.DescribeInstancesAsync(ec2Request);`)

Comment: follow https://stackoverflow.com/a/24663385/6797509

Comment: @Diado probably the first thing I tried. Didn't work

Comment: @HamedMoghadasi That is using `DescribeInstances` which is not available. Only `DescribeInstancesAsync` is available

Comment: "_Didn't work_" In what way?

Comment: Please include exception details in your question. Also note that AWS EC2 instance connection requires pem file, did you considered it? Does your machine already has AWS CLI set and up and running? That will give you good idea about connection process, default file locations of pem file etc. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

## Dotnet core sample code for counting AWS instances in a region

#### Initial set up not covered here

- You need to be familiar with Dotnet core basics and have installed the required Dotnet SDK.
- Follow the instructions [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-net/v3/developer-guide/net-dg-setup.html) for initial set up of the AWS SDK for .NET including setting up your AWS credentials.
- Add your config settings to `appsettings.Development.json`

```
"AWS" : {
  "ProfileName" : "<YourProfileName>",
  "Region" : "<your region>"
}
```

- The region will determine where the code below will look for instances.
- The steps below are for Dotnet core version 3.1

#### Create MVC project and install packages

- `dotnet new mvc –o WebProject` Create a new MVC project called `WebProject`
- `dotnet add package AWSSDK.EC2` Install the `AWSSDK.EC2` package
- `dotnet add package AWSSDK.Extensions.NETCore.Setup` Install the `AWSSDK.Extensions.NETCore.Setup` package to help using your AWS configuration in your code. See [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-net/v3/developer-guide/net-dg-config-netcore.html) for details.

#### Inject the configuration class into the HomeController

- Modify your `ConfigureServices` method in the `Startup.cs` file by adding this line `services.AddSingleton(Configuration);`

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddControllersWithViews();
    services.AddSingleton(Configuration);
}
```

- To your `HomeController.cs` file add the following line to the `usings` section `using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;`
- Modify the constructor so it looks like below. Also add the `_config` readonly field.

```
private readonly IConfiguration _config;

public HomeController(ILogger<HomeController> logger, IConfiguration config)
{
    _logger = logger;
    _config = config;
}
```

#### Add the code for getting data from AWS

- To your `HomeController.cs` file add the following to the `usings` section

```
using Amazon.EC2;
using Amazon.EC2.Model;
using System.Text;
```

- To your `HomeController.cs` add the following method for getting the instance count from AWS.

```
private async Task<string> GetInstances()
{
    // Print the number of Amazon EC2 instances.
    var options = _config.GetAWSOptions();
    IAmazonEC2 ec2 = options.CreateServiceClient<IAmazonEC2>();
    DescribeInstancesRequest ec2Request = new DescribeInstancesRequest();
    DescribeInstancesResponse ec2Response;

    var sb = new StringBuilder();

    try
    {
        ec2Response = await ec2.DescribeInstancesAsync(ec2Request);
        if (ec2Response.Reservations.Any())
        {
            sb.AppendFormat("The number of instances are {0} in {1}",ec2Response.Reservations[0].Instances.Count(), _config["AWS:Region"]);
        }
        else
        {
            sb.AppendFormat("No instances found in {0}", _config["AWS:Region"]);
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        sb.Append(ex.ToString());
    }

    return sb.ToString();
}
```

Modify you `HomeController.cs` index method to look like this:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Index()
{
    var numberOfInstances = await GetInstances();
    ViewData["numberOfInstances"] = numberOfInstances;
    return View();
}
```

- Add the following line to the related `Index.cshtml` view `<p>@ViewData["numberOfInstances"]</p>`
- Run the project and if all is well it will tell you how many instances were found in your specified region.